# Problem using jena for querying DBpedia endpoint (HttpException: 500 HTTP)

Tags: java, sparql, jena, dbpedia

I'm trying to obtain all the instance of a given class from DBpedia endpoint using Jena API. I noticed that a result set is limited to 10000 items. So for those classes that have more than 10000 I wrote the code shown below. However, this code is throwing an exception (*HttpException: 500 HTTP 500 error making the query: SPARQL Request Failed*). The code run fine when the class has less than 40000 instances, e.g, City. For those classes having more than 40000, like person, the execption is throwing.  Can somebody help me with this issue?

**Exception**

```
HttpException: 500 HTTP 500 error making the query: SPARQL Request Failed
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.HttpQuery.rewrap(HttpQuery.java:370)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.HttpQuery.execGet(HttpQuery.java:336)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.HttpQuery.exec(HttpQuery.java:288)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execResultSetInner(QueryEngineHTTP.java:351)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execSelect(QueryEngineHTTP.java:344)
    at org.jgnn.testes.dbpedia.DBpediaSPARQLDemo.getNumberOfInstancesByClassAndEndpoint(DBpediaSPARQLDemo.java:1637)
    at org.jgnn.testes.dbpedia.DBpediaSPARQLDemo.getNumberOfInstancesByClass(DBpediaSPARQLDemo.java:1602)
    at org.jgnn.testes.dbpedia.DBpediaSPARQLDemo.main(DBpediaSPARQLDemo.java:103)
```

```
public static int getNumberOfInstancesByClassAndEndpoint(String dbo_class,String regex_dbr, String sparqlEnpoint){


    int offset=0;
    int limit=10000;
    //total number of instances 
    int numberOfInstances=0;
    //number of instances of the iteration
    int numberOfInstancesOfIter=1;

    String dbo_class="dbo:Person";

    while (numberOfInstancesOfIter!=0) {
        String queryString="PREFIX dbo:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>\n"+
                "SELECT  DISTINCT ?x \n"+
                "WHERE \n"+
                "{ "+

                    "?x  a "+dbo_class+ " ."+ 
                 "} ORDER BY ?x LIMIT "+
                 limit+" OFFSET "+ offset;

        org.apache.jena.query.Query   query  = QueryFactory.create(queryString.toString());

        // Remote execution.
        try ( QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query) ) {
            // Set the DBpedia specific timeout.
            ((QueryEngineHTTP)qexec).setTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 120, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 

            // Execute.
            ResultSet rs = qexec.execSelect();

            while(rs.hasNext()){               
                QuerySolution qs=rs.next();                 
            }
            //how many instances in this iteration?
            numberOfInstancesOfIter=rs.getRowNumber();

            //update instance number
            numberOfInstances+=numberOfInstancesOfIter;
            //it ends if the number of intances of iteration is less than the limit
            if(numberOfInstancesOfIter < limit ){
                numberOfInstancesOfIter=0;
            }

            if (!(numberOfInstances==0)){
                System.out.println("ok");
            }

            java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        offset+=limit;

    }//while

    System.out.println("Number of instances of "+dbo_class +" is :"+numberOfInstances);
```

Comment: did you try the query that fails directly in the DBpedia web interface? And it's a public service, it might just be too busy when you"re sending too many queries in a short time or block you to prevent flooding the service.

Comment: Yes I tried theses queries in DBpedia endpoint, varying the offset (e,g, 40,000 or 1,000,0000) and it worked fine. An alternative solution would be  " select distinct ?x where  ?x a dbo:Person. " directly in jena api, since i'm looking for a way to process each of  the instance dynamically; but when I'm trying this solution, the jena api is returning only 10,000 instances. Why is returning only 10,000 instead of all the instances?

Comment: What do you mean by why? It is a public service free to use for everybody. What happens if people, bots, agents etc. are sending expensive queries all the time? What happens if those queries are just `select * where {?s ?p ?o}` - should the endpoint always return the whole dataset then? And then multiple request at the same time? The service would be stuck, down and unusable. The DBpedia dataset is free for download, there are also free triple stores to use. For production you cannot rely on a public free community service - what happens if the server is down for maintenance for e.g. a week?

Comment: For some reason my previous second comment was deleted, so one more time. Why are you not doing the counting directly on the SPARQL endpoint? Why not using a query like `select (count(?s) as ?cnt) where {?s a dbo:Person}` ?

Comment: Thanks for your returns. Well, I understood that the limit of 10,000 is necessary. My main goal is not counting all resources, I want to analyze dynamically some properties of a sample of the instances (about 100,000 dbo:Person or any other class). The last code works fine when I remove "ORDER BY ?x", but I need some sorting in order to return consistent results. How can I fix the issue When I run with "ORDER BY ?x"?

Comment: first of all, ORDER BY is expensive. The better way is too setup your own triple store locally and load the DBpedia dataset. It's simple to setup and everything is out there for free. just do it. If you use Virtuoso, then you can also modify the `MaxSortedTopRows` param that does lead to the exception you find on the public endpoint: `Virtuoso 22023 Error SR353: Sorted TOP clause specifies more then 50000 rows to sort. Only 40000 are allowed. Either decrease the offset and/or row count or use a scrollable cursor`

Comment: Other than that, a workaround is to wrap the ORDER BY part into a subquery: `select ?x { 
{select ?x {?x a dbo:Person} ORDER BY DESC(?x)}
}
LIMIT 10000 OFFSET 100000 `

Comment: To be clear here: an error, whether 4xx or 5xx is something from the remote server. All Jena is doing is reporting the error response from the remote server.

Comment: I agree with that, @AndyS.

Comment: Thanks @ASKW. The suggested  workaround works fine, but it very slow. In the future, I will try to deploy my own instance of DBpedia.  How can I deploy an instance of DBpedia quickly? Thanks.

Comment: take a triple store of your choice, download the DBpedia data and load it

Comment: The fastest way to deploy your own DBpedia mirror is to use the Pay-As-You-Go AWS-based AMI offerings from my employer. You can spin up the [DBpedia Snapshot AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07BQKYGYQ/) (mirroring <http://dbpedia.org/sparql>) or [DBpedia Live AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B012DSCFEK/) (mirroring <http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql>) with a few clicks, and a little wait time for the data to replicate within the AWS cloud.